# Misunderstanding concerning g++, dynamic and static linking on linux vs windows

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I'm a little confused by what I've learned today. I hope somebody can help me out.

I understand the concept of dynamic and static linking, but the problem is as follows. On windows, or at least the paradigm on windows, you can have a .lib (which is like .a) and .dll (which is like .so, except... different) and you must statically link in the .lib which contains code that calls functions from the dll at runtime. Is this correct? In other words, gcc or g++ must have .lib files available at compile/link time, and be able to find .dll files at runtime. Please correct any wrong assumptions here.

However, I'm splitting a few of my source files in my small application away because I want to make them a library. When I run g++ on my object files, with the -shared option, this basically creates a shared library (.so)? This is where the confusion arises. The *same* so file is needed *both* at link time and runtime? I have trouble understanding how I need it in the -L/-l option at link time but it still needs the file at runtime. Is this actually the norm? Is a dll fundamentally different?

Finally, a final question. Take a library like boost on Windows. I built boost according to the instructions. In the end, the stage/lib directory contains libraries in a repeating sequence of name.a, name.dll.a, name.dll. What is the purpose of this scheme? I know I need the dll files at runtime, but when I use the -L/-l option at link time, what files is it using THEN?

Sorry if this is really scattered, but I hope someone can help clear this up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tip for boost libraries on Windows. At least in Visual C++ the header files have pragmas that inform the linker what libraries to link with and the -l options aren't needed at all. Could be different for mingw I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On windows, or at least the paradigm on windows, you can have a .lib (which is like .a) and .dll (which is like .so, except... different) and you must statically link in the .lib which contains code that calls functions from the dll at runtime. Is this correct?

Yes and no. That is one way that DLLs work on Windows, but it is not the only way.

You can load a DLL manually, using Win32 API calls. But if you do, you have to get function pointers manually to actually access the DLL. The purpose of the import library (that static library you're talking about) is to do this automatically.

The nice thing about doing it manually is that you can pick and choose what DLLs you want. This is how some applications provide plugin support. Users write a DLL that exports a well-defined set of API functions. Your program loads them from a directory, and they bundle the function pointers for each DLL into its own object, which represents the interface to that plugin.

GCC works the same way, *on Windows*. Building a DLL produces a DLL and an import library. It's a ".a" file instead of ".lib" because of the compiler, but it still does the same thing.

On Linux, .so files are a combination of the .dll and the import library. So you link to the .so when compiling the program in question, and it does the same job as linking to the import library.

Comment: You can also load .so's as plugins AFAIK. See for example flashplugin.so for Firefox. Also note that since around version 4.4-4.5, GCC on Windows can link directly to a DLL if it exports all the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It's just two ways of giving infos at compile time about the shared library. Maybe a comparison would explain it better ?

In Windows, it's : "You will use a shared library (.dll) and here (.a or .dll.a) is the manual on how to use it."

In Linux, it's :" You will use a shared library (.so) so look at it beforehand (.so) so you'll know how to use it."